# Execute a Python script from Expect

Tags: python, expect

I am using [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for automation, and I want to execute a Python script from it. But it is not working... This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn  "./os_fun"
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn  "./os_fun.py"
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn  python "./os_fun(.py)"
```

The "os_fun.py" contains the simple code:

```
#!/bin/usr/python
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

I would also like to mention that I must use Expect only and not Bash as I need to do the automation part, and I am not supposed to use Pexpect.

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: @cdarke not working ==> The script is not being executed via Expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to `Expect`, you always have to expect something, so that `Expect` will wait for it. Else, it will proceed as such. Simply spawning a processing does not make sense, as `Expect` don't wait to see for it which in turn makes the user not to see the output as well.

In your case, you just have to run the code and see the output till the program completes. I hope my understanding is correct.

```
!/usr/bin/expect
spawn python os_fun.py
expect eof; # will wait till 'eof' seen
```

Here, `expect` command will wait till it sees close of the running program. 
Default timeout is 10 seconds which can be changed as

```
set timeout 60; # Timeout value as 1 min
```

Comment: ,thanks fr yr help first as yr solution worked. But as you said "the `expect` command will work till it sees close of the running progam" , I do not want to close the program. It is required to keep the program running as it will be interacting with another program which will be invoked just after that(python script). I am a novice to expect so cud u plz help me out here....

Comment: `It expect command will work till it sees the close`. - I said this because of `eof`. Till what point you want to wait, add `expect <word-to-wait-for>`, then using `send` command you can send any commands. Using `interact` will help you on user interactive process.